# Ubuntu SOCKS proxy setup with two interfaces - how to pass DNS

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, proxy, socks, dante

I setup a SOCKSv5 server (Dante) on Ubuntu with two ethernet interfaces:

- eth0 is connected to my WAN with a static routable IP
- eth1 is connected to my LAN with a private IP

I have a client connected on the LAN, and I'm able to ping the LAN port of the proxy using its IP address.  However, I'm not able to resolve DNS names from that computer.  The default gateway for my client points to the LAN of the proxy.

When I do a wireshark trace on the proxy, I see the DNS request coming in on eth1, but I don't see anything coming out of eth0.  If I enable ip_forward on the proxy, then I see the DNS coming out of eth0 but the source iP is the private IP, which isn't routable.  Is there any way for the proxy to handle DNS?